# AWS: data transformation from dynamodb to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, data-science

I have a daily table of logs (around 10m inputs every day) stored in DynamoDB.

In order to do analysis I need it transferred into Redshift. Furthermore I need to create new columns out of the existing ones by parsing a string (nvarchar(250)). My idea was to use the COPY command and transfer data from DynamoDB to Redshift and then use UDFs to create new columns.

The problem with this approach is that it takes a lot of time to complete (both parts) and it keeps failing (status of query ABORTED): I am transferring around 10 days of data in one copy command.

What do you think should be better approach: using some Amazon services like data pipeline or EMR maybe? or doing the same thing but organized differently?

Answer (score 1):

My design suggestion is not store your data in dynamodb. Because in cost perspective when you do copy command it consume highest throughput value you set for dynamo db.

Not sure how do you set primary key values and what is the current through put value you set for dynamodb.

For this my solution is write data into s3 in required format of redshift storage. From s3 process your data in to redshift cluster using data pipeline in periodic/one time activity.

Aws data pipe line by default use EMR to process your data.

If you need more cleansing before you store data consider using Spark in EMR.

But before this you need to say. What is the size of 10m records size and you have option to adopt my suggestion like writing to s3. If yes you need to design by considering performance/ cost optimized process.

If you need more help post comments will contribute my best suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! one question: do you think that data pipeline can be used for creating new columns while transferring data from dynamodb to s3, or should the data be transferred first and then transformed (in redshift)?

Comment: No data pipeline not support this feature. Why you can't write s3 file with data you need?. If you want to do it from dynamo db. Go for aws glue or use dynamo db streams wrapper and process records in lambda and write to s3(but I strongly disagree this solution in long term/ cost/ performance factors )

Comment: as far as I've seen, aws glue (I thought about it as well) is only available in one region: us east (n. virginia) and my data is in the other region...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) to setup an ETL(Extract Transform Load) job to move your data from DynamoDB to Redshift.

Comment: How is that achievable using Glue? If I want to move data from DynamoDb to s3 or Redshift?